# Defining a string in an angular directive

Tags: angularjs

```
<input type="file" my-file="angularVar" my-file-type="MY_STRING" />
```

`angularVar` is just a normal var on the scope, that I want to bind task-file to.

How do I make `my-file-type` accept a normal string though? Just something to pass through to the directive?

I have this:

```
scope: {
    taskFile: '=',
    taskFileType: '='
},
```

But what I want in my "link" logic is something like:

```
if (scope.myFileType != null && scope.myFileType == "MY_STRING") {
    // do something
}
```

How can I do that? Without it trying to bind to some non-existant var called MY_STRING.

Cheers

Comment: if you want to pass hardcoded value from the attribute then you could easily achieve by having `attrs.myFileType` inside your directive..no need to include that in your directive isolated scope..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a variable in scope with `@`

Like this

```
scope : {
  myFileType:'@'
}
```

Then in html

```
<input type="file" my-file="angularVar" my-file-type="'MY_STRING'" />
```

Comment: I hope that should be single quote instead of tilde key.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal: that was backtick, not tilde. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a single quote to denote it as a string and use `@` binding instead of `=`:

```
 my-file-type="'MY_STRING'"
```